# MS-DOS "Divide Overflow" error

Tags: ms-dos

When I attempt an installation of an application in MS-DOS, I receive the following error:
"Divide Overflow." What is the meaning of this error and how do I fix it?

The install procedure is:

1. Partition my HDD
2. Format C drive
3. Install MS-DOS
   4  Add the flowing lines to `config.sys`

   ```
   DEVICE=C:\DOS\HIMEM.SYS
   DEVICE=C:\DOS\EMM386.EXE RAM
   DEVICE=C:\DOS\RAMDRIVE.SYS 6000 512 64 /e
   ```
4. Insert my floppy application and then restart

It works properly the Virtual machine `Q emulator` but I receive a "Divide Overflow" error on the real machine (Vectra HP PC).

Comment: There is probably a timing loop somewhere in the code, and your new[er] machine is *way* faster than it ever expected, generating a divide-by-zero error. What application is it? Do you have the source code?

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of options.

1. FreeDOS:Instead of installing MsDos, install that one
2. Emulator on the machine: Istead of installing it on a virtual machine, do it on the real one.
3. DosBOX: Istead of using Q emulator, use DosBOX, multi-platform, and works like a charm on any machine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how old this system is, but it may have subtle incompatibilites in the chipset that cause it not to really be compatible with DOS or all DOS applications.  It's also possible there's a newer CPU feature that is causing an issue.  It could be that the application is doing something weird with invalid instructions

Try going into the BIOS and disabling any extended CPU features, any caching, and any onboard hardware that you don't need for this application.

Comment: i should tell to you i use 486 and pentium 2 main board ...

Comment: @repozitor, and it fails on both? I know that 200MHz P2’s and up were too fast and needed to be slowed down via software.